# Why is git-svn is randomly changing my root directory to the parent?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'm trying to `git-svn` to work on a private shadowcat svn server.

```
git svn clone -s http://dev.catalystframework.org/repos/Catalyst/Catalyst-Plugin-ConfigLoader/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/ecarroll/code/perl/foo/Catalyst-Plugin-ConfigLoader/.git/
Using higher level of URL: http://dev.catalystframework.org/repos/Catalyst/Catalyst-Plugin-ConfigLoader => http://dev.catalystframework.org/repos/Catalyst
```

What doesn't that work? It looks like http://dev.catalystframework.org/repos/Catalyst/Catalyst-Plugin-ConfigLoader/ has the standard layout.

Is there a sane simple way to get git to pull from an svn repo?

Comment: Works fine for me (Git 1.7). Did you provide the full output of the command?

Answer (score 15):

I'm a little late in answering now that the Catalyst-Plugin-ConfigLoader project has migrated to Git, but I'll answer in case someone runs into a similar problem with a different svn project.

`git svn` tries to be helpful by searching for the root of the svn repository and using that instead of the URL you give it.  I find it annoying, but fortunately there's a workaround:  use the `--no-minimize-url` option.

From the `git svn` documentation (`git help svn`):

> `--no-minimize-url`
>
> When tracking multiple directories (using `--stdlayout`, `--branches`, or `--tags` options), `git svn` will attempt to connect to the root (or highest allowed level) of the Subversion repository.  This default allows better tracking of history if entire projects are moved within a repository, but may cause issues on repositories where read access restrictions are in place.  Passing `--no-minimize-url` will allow `git svn` to accept URLs as-is without attempting to connect to a higher level directory.  This option is off by default when only one URL/branch is tracked (it would do little good).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and used the --no-minimize-url option.  This allowed the clone to succeed, but something like half of the tags were missing.  It turns out that prohibiting the clone from going up a level meant it couldn't see a previous repo rename that happened.  Once I removed the --no-minimize-url option, the missing tags showed up.